# Docker image rabbitmq, apt broke

Tags: linux, ubuntu, curl, dockerfile, apt

when I try `apt-get update`, I get this error:

> E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/https could not be found.

Solution:

`sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https`

But when I try that I get this error:

> E: Unable to locate package apt-transport-https

Solution:

```
apt-get update
```

So I am in a loop...

Any ideas?
Usually all this is installed but I am using rabbitmq docker image.

Thanks

[image: Error]

Comment: `apt-get update` does not require `curl`.  E.g., I can start an Ubuntu docker image, which by default does not include `curl`, and I can run `apt-get update` without a problem. It looks like you're missing part of your `apt` installation. How did you end up in this situation? In what environment are you running?

Comment: I am using docker rabbitmq:3.6.6-management image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That docker image has problems

I have changed:

```
FROM rabbitmq:3.6.6-management
```

to

```
FROM rabbitmq:management
```

And now it works, I hope this helps others
Thank you larsks

Answer (score 4):

The image you're using seems to have a broken `apt` installation, but you can fix it like this:

```
ln -s http /usr/lib/apt/methods/https
```

This will allow `apt-get update` to connect to the remote repositories, but you're going to encounter a second problem: this image is based on Debian Jessie, which is no longer maintained, and there are no longer any `jessie-updates` repositories, so you'll see:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-amd64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://www.rabbitmq.com/debian/dists/testing/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Undetermined Error [IP: 104.20.62.197 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

However, you should still be able to install packages.

Comment: Exactly that, but I can not install any package.  If I do that when I do apt update docker finished build with error and if I do not do that I get Unable to locate package or package has not installation candidate

Comment: FWIW, I was able to install packages without a problem using the same image, but it looks like you've upgraded to a more recent image that does not present the same problem.